# Sort nodes by extracted inner text and maintain index association or hack around in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with rows(divs in the case below).  Within those rows are nodes with text.  I am trying to look at the inner text and sort the rows according to the inner text.  I have the sorting by text down, just don't know how to put the nodes back on the screen in the right order.  Here is what I have:

```
<div>
    <i> - Name: Casper</i><br/>
</div>
<div>
    <i> - Name: Joe</i><br/>
</div>
<div>
    <i> - Name: Allen</i>
</div>


var originalNameNodes = $('i:contains(" - Name:")');
var numNames = originalNameNodes.length;
var namesForSorting = []

var i = 0;
originalNameNodes.each(function(){    
    namesForSorting[i] = $(this).text().replace(" - Name: ", "");    
    i = i + 1;
});

namesForSorting.sort();

for(var j = 0; j < numNames; j++){
    var sortedNameNode = originalNameNodes.find('i:contains('+namesForSorting[j]+')');
    $('body').append(sortedNameNode);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do that like so :

```
var elems = $('div').filter(function() {
        return $('i', this).text().indexOf('Name:');
    }),
    parent = elems.first().parent();

elems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $('i', a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($('i', b).text().toUpperCase());
});

$.each(elems, function(idx, itm) { parent.append(itm); });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhZLD/3/)

First we get the div's, and we target all divs and filter them and only return the div's that contains an `<i>` element, and if that `<i>` element contains the string `'Name:'`
There are many ways to get the div's, I just went with this one.

As they div's are all siblings in the markup, just getting the parent of the first one would do, or we could even use a selector like `$('body')` or anything else that gets us the parent element containing the div's.

The `sort()` function is where it happens, we don't sort the `<i>` elements, but the `<div>` elements, as that's easier, and then we just look up the text in the children `<i>` element and compare `a > b` etc. and that sorts the array of elements based on the text in `<i>`, so all we have to do then is rearrange them in the DOM, and we use `append()` for that in a loop to move the elements in the same order as the array we have sorted.

Comment: That is pretty ingenious.  So basically you are making an index based on the inner text of the 'i' nodes, running a sort on them, and appending those nodes back to their parents?  Any additional plain english explanation on this would be great as I think this is a very handy technique.  Thanks again.

Comment: @carter - added some explanation to what is going on!

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess sort() should be run on a plain nodeList, so [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhZLD/5/) would be more correct, but the above code seems to work as well, so probably not an issue !

Comment: So I guess there is a slight snag... What about for this structure: tr>td>nobr>small>i    Keeping the entire contents of tr in tact.

Comment: You sort the outer elements, in that case probably the TR's, but inside the sort() function you decide what to sort on, could be anything, but in this case you would look up the td>nobr>small>i elements and compare the text inside those, just like above where `$('i', a).text()` is compared against `$('i', b).text()`, and where `a` and `b` are the div's etc.